# Mongoose Populate not working

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Hello i have this Schema(called schema.js):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RoomSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
  people: { type: Number, required: true },
  childrens: {type: Number, required: true},
  total: {type: Number, required: true}
});

var Room = mongoose.model('Room', RoomSchema);

var AvSchema = new Schema({
  roomId:  {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Room'},
  people: { type: Number, required: true },
  childrens: {type: Number, required: true},
  total: {type: Number, required: true}
});

var Av = mongoose.model('Av', AvSchema);

module.exports = {
  Room: Room,
  Av: Av
};
```

in my Route file :

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var model = require('../models/Schema');

  app.get('/api/rooms', function(req, res) {
    model.Room.find(function(err, rooms) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json(rooms);
    });
  });


  app.get('/api/av', function(req, res) {
    model.Av.find().populate('roomId').exec(function(err, av) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json(av);
    });
  });
};
```

A pic of the db :
[image]

GET /api/rooms - response:

```
[{
  "_id": "5444d0dd9a31437167eea816",
  "name": "Single",
  "people": 1,
  "childrens": 1,
  "total": 4
}, {
  "_id": "5444d1009a31437167eea817",
  "name": "Double",
  "people": 2,
  "childrens": 2,
  "total": 10
}]
```

When i call api/rooms looks fine but when i call api/av i got an empty array [] .... Any idea what i do wrong? I should mention that i have inserted records in av collection for both roomsID

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default, Mongoose pluralizes the model name to come up with the name of the collection, so Mongoose is looking in the `avs` collection instead of `av`.

You can explicitly set the collection name by passing that as the third parameter to `model`:

```
var Av = mongoose.model('Av', AvSchema, 'av');
```

Comment: SMH. Don't know if Mongoose is trying to be too smart for itself sometimes. I had to do this: .populate('friendss'); Note the two ss.

Comment: @daCoda,  same happened to me.  if you have a field that is "friends",  you will need to do populate ('friendss')

Answer (score 19):

I had the same issue but none of the answers worked for me.

I wanted to populate a document after it was queried.

This didn't work:

```js
// IIFE for async/await
( async() => {

    var user = await User.findOne( { _id } );

    await user.populate( 'comments' ); // Doesn't work

} );
```

The [Mongoose Documentation explains](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-populate) that when calling `.populate()` without a callback it won't be executed. Instead you need to use `.populate().execPopulate()`:

```js
// IIFE for async/await
( async() => {

    var user = await User.findOne( { _id } );

    await user.populate( 'comments' ).execPopulate(); // Works as expected

} );
```

Comment: Error: `execPopulate()` is not a function

Comment: This works with Mongoose 5. 

`execPopulate()` was removed in Mongoose 6: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#removed-execpopulate

Answer (score 8):

Similar to CodyBugstein's answer, I'm posting why it wasn't working in my case, even though it's not the same case as OP's.

I was trying to populate the "pro" field of my schema in a `.post('save')` hook, as so:

```
mySchema.post('save', function(doc, next) {
    console.log(doc.pro); // Expected to log ObjectID
    doc.populate("pro"); // Populate field
    console.log(doc.pro); // Expected to log actual pro document
}
```

However, **the 2nd `console.log` was also logging the ObjectID** instead of the doc.

After struggling with this for a solid hour and trying different approaches, I found out that all I had to do was use promises and call `execPopulate()` so that it returned a fully-fledged promise. I used `async/await` but you could use `.then` too:

```
mySchema.post('save', async function(doc, next) {
    console.log(doc.pro); // Expected to log ObjectID
    await doc.populate("pro").execPopulate(); // Populate field
    console.log(doc.pro); // Expected to log actual pro document
}
```

This way, the 2nd `console.log` did log the entire pro doc as expected :)

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to add the ref property to the schema for the property you are trying to populate. E.g.

```
// ...
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  reservationId: {
    type: Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Reservation' // <-- don't forget the ref
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
// ...
```

See [Mongoose Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the most popular result for the query

> mongoose populate not working

I'll include the reason it wasn't working for me, even though it's not a direct answer to this already solved question, in the hopes it will help someone

The problem for me was that I had specified fields in `select({..}` but not the field I was trying to populate.

Answer (score 1):

Also check that your schema doesn't have `depopulate` in `toJSON` or `toObject` option set to true. (facepalm myself)

[See all schema options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it is was due to incorrect data. The Ids which I want to populate got deleted from the main table.
So when I do populate it didn't filled the populated data because the Ids were not in the table.

Comment: I came from top to bottom and that was my problem too ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

**2023 Mongoose v 7.6.1**

If you want a property of a document to be populatable it must be declared at the schema creation level with the 'ref' property.

`new Schema(property: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'foo' })`

Then a populate call on the document will suffice.

`await document.populate('foo');`

Answer (score 0):

add this in your model

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "product name must be provide"],
      minlength: [3, "Name length minimum is 3"],
      maxlength: [50, "Name length maximum is 50"],
      trim: true,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: [true, "price must be provide for product"],
      default: 0,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "product description is required"],
      trim: true,
    },
   
  {
    timestamps: true,

    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true,
    },
    toObject: {
      virtuals: true,
    },
  }
);
```

Example:

```
productSchema.virtual("reviews", {
  ref: "Review",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "product",
  justOne: false,
});
```

How to use:

```
products = await productModel.find({}).populate("reviews");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's solved but this might help. (using mongoose v6.6.1)

My schema:

```
products: {
  type: [
    {
      product: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Product",
        required: [true, "{VALUE} can not be null"],
      },
      quantity: Number,
    },
  ],
}
```

My wrong populate query:

```
populate({ path: "products", select: "name" })
```

Correct populate query:

```
populate({ path: "products.product", select: "name" })
```

Answer (score 0):

What happened to me was, i was not saving the nested object, i was just building, and referecing it to the parent object.

```
order{
orderItem[]
}
```

then when i called populate, it was giving me empty data.i forgot to save the orderitem when creating, but we have to save.