# How to return the object in an array object in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I currently have a UserModel and a House model where the house model contains an array of user objects. However, when I return I want to return an array of user objects instead of just users objectId. How do I accomplish this?

For example, if I run

`HouseModel.findbyId("asdf")`
it returns:

```
_id: "asdf"
"name": "name",
    "users": [
        "620044aa7811fb4ab4619e44",
"620044aa7811fb4ab4619e45"
    ],
```

Any help would be appreciated

but I want to return:

```
``
_id: "asdf"
"name": "name",
    "users": [
        {_id: "620044aa7811fb4ab4619e44", name: "bob" age: 7,},
{_id: "620044aa7811fb4ab4619e45", name: "bob" age: 7,}
    ],
``
```

HouseSchema

```
const houseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    users: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            default: [],
            required: true,
        }
    ],
```

UserSchema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        unique: true,
    },
```

Comment: can you share your house and user schema?

Comment: @sinabariaji edited accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

`HouseModel.findbyId("asdf").populate('users')`

Comment: This returns an empty array for some reason. I even changed it to `populate({path: 'users', model: 'User'});` but it still gives an empty array

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526779/mongoose-populate-not-working)